# odata, nhibernate generates ORA-12704: character set mismatch

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, odata

I have two classes:

```
public class DepotType
{
   public virtual Depot Depot {get;set;}
   /*other properties*/
}

public class Depot
{
   public virtual string Name {get;set;}
   /*other properties*/
}
```

I made the following odata query:

```
http://localhost:63236/OData/DepotPlaces?$expand=Depot&$filter=Depot/Name eq 'asd'
```

but, I get the following error: `ORA-12704: character set mismatch`

Nhibernate generates the following sql:

```
SELECT ...
FROM "DepotPlaces" depotplace0_
LEFT OUTER JOIN "Depots" depot1_ ON depotplace0_."depotId"=depot1_."id"
WHERE 
   cast(CASE WHEN depotplace0_."depotId" IS NULL 
             THEN :p0 
             ELSE depot1_."depotName" 
       END AS VARCHAR2(255))=:p1

:p0 = NULL [Type: String (0)], :p1 = 'asd' [Type: String (0)]
```

I tried to write similar `LINQ` query manually:

```
var test = _repository.Query().Where(d => d.Depot.Name == "asd").ToList();
```

The generated sql:

```
SELECT ...
FROM "DepotPlaces" depotplace0_
INNER JOIN "Depots" depot1_ ON depotplace0_."depotId"=depot1_."id"
WHERE depot1_."depotName"=:p0;

:p0 = 'asd' [Type: String (0)]
```

The main difference in the `CAST` operator. I don't know why it exist in the first `sql` query. And, if I run this query in the `SQL Developer` I get the same error. If I delete the `p0` parameter and write `NULL` then script works correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is found. I have to add the following option:

```
[EnableQuery(HandleNullPropagation = HandleNullPropagationOption.False)]
```